# VBA Word Hide/Show Button

Tags: vba, ms-office, ms-word

I have created a button in Word which can help me to save files much more easier. I have a question related to this button from the document. I have read that it is not possible to hide or show the button. So I though I will delete the button which worked, but once the project got a bit complicated.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    CommandButton1.Select
    Selection.Delete

    UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

My questions are:

1. Is it possible to use hide/show command for the CommandButtton1?
2. If 1 is not possible then is it possible to call from UserForm the function CommandButton1 and delete it from there if a certain value is true?

Answer (score 1):

1. Unfortunately there is no way to hide/unhide buttons in Word, but deleting them instead is a good solution for this problem.
2. You can simply write a method  and call that method from a UserForm.

   ```
   Public Sub test()
       CommandButton1.Select
       Selection.Delete
   End Sub
   ```

   Now all you need to do is call the method :

   ```
   call test
   ```

Edit:

```
Public Sub test()
  CommandButton1.Select
  Selection.Delete

  'All the Other code
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  call test
End Sub
```

Now you can just call the `sub test` to execute the same code as the CommandButton1 does.

Hope I could help.

Comment: My problem is how can I call CommandButton1 (which is in the "ThisDocument" and the call is from UserForm? How can I call the button which is in the word document and not in the Userform?

Comment: You don´t need to call the CommandButton1 if you just write all the code you want to be executed into the method.